nx 18 + nest + webpack + serverless breaking with error src/main.handler is undefined or not exported
I am trying to setup serverless api using stack:
nx 18 + nest + webpack + serverless
node: 20.x
gives error:
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "src/main.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: src/main.handler is undefined or not exported",
        "    at UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1122:15)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}

Minimum reproduction code
https://github.com/pratik-github/demo-nx-nest-serverless
Steps to reproduce
use node v20.x
configure aws cli credentials
npm install
npx nx deploy graphql

Deployment is successful but when I hit api endpoint I get error; Internal server error
Steps to reproduce
use node v20.x
configure aws cli credentials
npm install
npx nx deploy graphql
API to run successfully without error
